# $f(f(x))=a^3\left(x^2-(2+b)x+2b-\frac2a\right)\left(x^2-(2+b)x+2b-\frac ba\right)$, $a\ne0$ has exactly one real zeroes $5$.

Tags: calculus, roots, quadratics, maxima-minima, quartics

> Let $f(x)=a(x-2)(x-b)$, where $a,b\in R$ and $a\ne0$. Also, $f(f(x))=a^3\left(x^2-(2+b)x+2b-\frac2a\right)\left(x^2-(2+b)x+2b-\frac ba\right)$, $a\ne0$ has exactly one real zeroes $5$. Find the minima and maxima of $f(x)$.

$f(f(x))$ is a quartic equation. So, it would have $4$ roots. Its real root should occur in pair because complex roots occur in pair. So, I failed to understand the meaning of 'exactly one real zero' in the question. Does that mean its real roots are equal and they are equal to $5$?

Since $f(x)$ has a zero at $2$, $f(f(2))=f(0)=2ab$. But even RHS of $f(f(x))$ is coming out to be $2ab$ at $x=2$.

Putting $x=5$ in $f(f(x))$ gives an equation in $a^2$ and $b^2$. Don't know what to do with it.

Also, $f(x)=a(x^2-(2+b)x+2b)$

$f'(x)=a(2x-2-b)=0\implies x=\frac{2+b}2$ is the minima or maxima.

How to proceed next? Do the critical points of $f(x)$ tell us anything about $f(f(x))$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737712/the-quadratic-polynomial-px-has-a-zero-at-x-2-the-polynomial-ppx-ha

Answer (score 1):

From the given form of $f(f(x))$,

$$\begin{align*}
f(f(x)) &= a^3 \left[x^2 - (2+b)x + 2b - \frac 2a\right]\left[x^2 - (2+b)x + 2b - \frac ba\right]\\
&= a^3 \left[(x-2)(x-b) - \frac 2a\right]\left[(x-2)(x-b) - \frac ba\right]
\end{align*}$$

$(x-2)(x-b)$ has roots at $x=2$ and $x=b$. If we ignore the $-\frac2a$ and $-\frac ba$, then $f(f(2)) = f(f(b)) = 0$.

But if $\frac2a$ and $\frac ba$ are just negative enough, then these two factors of $f(f(x))$:

$$\left[(x-2)(x-b) - \frac 2a\right]\left[(x-2)(x-b) - \frac ba\right]$$

One of these factors would be strictly positive, and the other factor would have a double zero at the $x$ that minimises $(x-2)(x-b)$. Then overall, the product would have just one distinct real zero.

At this point, the requirement that $f(f(5))=0$ becomes useful. Consider that if $x=5$ minimises $(x-2)(x-b)$, then $x = \frac{2+b}{2} = 5$ and so $b=8$.

---

Then choose $a$ (which would be negative) so that within the product

$$\left[(x-2)(x-8) - \frac 2a\right]\left[(x-2)(x-8) - \frac 8a\right],$$

the minimum of the first factor is $0$ at $x=5$. The second factor would be strictly positive.

$$\begin{align*}
(5-2)(5-8) - \frac 2a &= 0\\
a &= -\frac 29\\
\end{align*}$$

To double check:

$$\begin{align*}
f(f(x)) &= a^3\left[(x-2)(x-8) - \frac 2a\right]\left[(x-2)(x-8) - \frac 8a\right]\\
&= a^3 [(x-2)(x-8) + 9][(x-2)(x-8) + 36]\\
&= a^3[(x-5+3)(x-5-3)+9][(x-5+3)(x-5-3)+36]\\
&= a^3 [(x-5)^2 - 3^2+9][(x-5)^2 - 3^2 + 36]\\
&= a^3 (x-5)^2 [(x-5)^2 +27]
\end{align*}$$

And back to the question,

$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= -\frac 29(x-2)(x-8)\\
f(5) &= -\frac 29(3)(-3) = 2
\end{align*}$$

and the $2$ is a global maximum. This makes sense because

$$f(f(5)) = f(2) = 0,$$

and $f(x)$ is never equal to $8$ for real $x$, otherwise those real $x$ would add zeroes to $f(f(x)) = f(8)$.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for the answer. But I couldn't follow this: "But if $\frac2a$ and $\frac ba$ are just negative enough, then these two factors of $f(f(x))$"

Comment: @aarbee If drawing a graph is more helpful to you: consider just $y = (x-2)(x-b)$, which is a parabola that opens upwards and has one or two $x$-intercepts. Adding a constant term $-\frac 2a$ (or $-\frac ba$) shifts the parabola $y = (x-2)(x-b) - \frac 2a$ vertically. With the right $a$, the parabola would just touch the $x$-axis at the $x$ that minimises $(x-2)(x-b)$. The $x$-intercepts are also the roots of $f(f(x))$, and it's given that $f(f(x))$ has just one distinct real root.

Comment: Hi. I understood your comment. Thanks. Back to the answer, I understand that one factor would be zero and the other would be positive. But how did you decide that it's the first factor that would zero?

Comment: @aarbee The minimum of $(x-2)(x-8)$ is negative (at $x=5$). When adding $-\frac 2a$ or $-\frac ba$ to $(x-2)(x-8)$ in order to increase the minimum to zero, firstly both $-\frac 2a > 0$ and $-\frac 8a > 0$, and the $-\frac 8a > -\frac 2a$. That means

$$\left[(x-2)(x-8)-\frac8a\right] > \left[(x-2)(x-8)-\frac2a\right]$$

for every $x$, particularly at $x=5$ where both factors are at their respective minimum.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $a > 0$, then there are two solutions to $a(x-2)(x-b) = 2$, and thus $f(f(x))$ has more than one zero. So we know $a < 0$.

Since $f(f(x))$ is a downward-opening quartic with only one zero, it takes on no positive values. Thus, the maximum of $f$ must be no larger than its smallest zero. Additionally, since $f(f(x))$ actually achieves the value $0$, that means that its maximum value is *equal* to its smaller zero. Since have $f(f(x_{max})) = 0$ and we want $f(f(5)) = 0$, we must have $x_{max} = 5$. It's not hard to see $x_{max} = 1 + b/2$, so we must have $b= 8$. Since that's larger than $2$, we must have $f(x_{max}) = 2$.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, why are you putting $f(x)=2?$

Comment: @aarbee $f$ has two roots, $2$ and $b$. If $b = 8$, then the smaller of those two roots is $2$.

Comment: Hi. I am talking about the first sentence of the answer. You have taken $f(x)=2$. What is the motivation for this?

Comment: @aarbee Oh, I see. Since $f(2) = 0$, then if there are two solutions to $f(x) = 2$, then there are at least two solutions to $f(f(x)) = 0$. Since we're told that there's only one solution, that rules out the possibility that $a > 0$.

Comment: Hi. I have understood your comment, thanks. Back to the answer, I understood that the maxima of $f(f(x))$ would occur at $x=5$, and that of $f(x)$ would occur at $x=1+b/2$. But how did you equate the two?

Comment: @aarbee Let $z$ be the smaller zero of $f$. We know that $f(x) \le z$ for all $x$, since if that weren't true, $f(f(x))$ would have positive values. We also know that, since $f(f(x)) = 0$ somewhere, then we must have $f(x) = z$ somewhere, and that this value is necessarily the maximum of $f(x)$. So, since $f(f(5)) = 0$, we have $f(5) = z$, and thus the maximum of $f$ occurs at $x = 5$.

Comment: Sorry I lost you at the second sentence when you say $f(x)\le z$ for all $x$

Comment: (I am taking time to respond because I like to come back to it again and again and try to understand on my own. If I still struggle then I ask.)

Comment: @aarbee $f(x)$ takes on all values less than its maximum. If its maximum is greater than $z$, then it takes on some values $y$ between its two roots, and then $f(f(y)) > 0$, which can't happen.